# Is this correct to say?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"forced to make due with"

I don't know it doesn't sound right to me, is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Should be *make do with*. Happens because some people pronounce *do* and *due* the same, hence  * *much adue*.

Comment: Grammar, yes. Idiomacy, no. Currency, sadly, yes, which influences future idiomacy.

Comment: It’s make do, not make due.  Look it up.

Comment: @Minty That could be an answer.